# What kind of IR controller is required to drive a 15m LED strip?

Tags: led-strip, rgb

I have to light a 15m RGB LED strip but I don't know how many amps the IR controller (sensor) is required to drive.

There are three LED strips, each 5 metres, and I need to connect them together with only one power adapter and one sensor.

My sensor is working properly to light 15 metre RGB LED but the sensor only works in one 5 metre LED strip.  It is a 4A IR controller (sensor).

Could you tell me, what kind of LED controller is required to drive a 15 metre LED strip?

Comment: sorry, my adapter is working properly but not sensor.it was my mistake...........now there should be no confusion.....thanks

Comment: What is the name of your controller? What LED stripe do you have? Do you want to control them independently? Out of your question one can't really tell, what you're asking for...

Answer (score 1):

First question from my side: Do you want to control the LED strips seperatly or do you want all three to have the same colour?

Case 1: you want to have all LED strips the same (the easy solution)

If you have a soldering iron, you can simply connect the three stips together. Be sure to connect the 4 lines correctly (R of strip 1 goes to R on strip 2, G goes to G, etc.). This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OLQs7S_Ou8U) shows you, how you need to solder it.

Case 2: you want to control the three strips independently

If each strip has different colours, you will need three controllers. Because one controller is only capable of driving a single stip of LEDs. Just buy two more controllers and AC adapters and you should be fine, if each stip has its connector for a contoller.

I'm assuming that you have LED strips that can have only one colour at the same time, e.g. something like [this](http://www.conrad.ch/ce/de/product/591431/Eurolite-SMD5050-LED-Streifen-LED-Strip-RGB-LED-15-m?ref=searchDetail). (not an addressable one, like [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11842))

Independent of your choice, a contoller with 4 amps should be fine to drive a 15m LED strip.